# KDE: kwallet error after relogin

Tags: kde, reboot, session, kwallet

Every time I log out of KDE session and log back in, a window pops up asking me to provide password for `kwallet`. And then it won't accept the password at all. So I need to reboot to make it right again. For me it looks like it's having troubles with permissions somewhere or sessions aren't being terminated correctly. Any suggestions?

Linux Mint 18.1